# regular expression to match exactly 0.[001 to 999]

Tags: regex

I tried `(^[0]?)\.*(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,3}?$`expression to match input value which should only accept 0.[001 to 999] , now the problem is :

it is matching 012 or 090 etc numbers too.

I wanted the expression to match exactly 0.[001 - 999]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Anything wrong with `^0\.\d\d\d$`?

Comment: Matches 0.000 too but yes, that should basically work

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, eventually.  Should probably be `0\.(?:00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$` -- ugh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had `\.*` which matches 0 or more. It matches 0, therefore you get to match stuff like 012.

```
^0\.[0-9]{2}[1-9]$
```

Matches a `0`, then a `.`, then `[0-9]` twice, then `[1-9]`

Edit: Jonathan is right, this doesn't properly match stuff like `0.010`.

```
^0\.[0-9]{3}$
```

and then ensure that it is not 0.000 would work.

Alternatively try this ugly one: `^0\.(?:[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[0-9][1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2})$`

Comment: That won't recognize 0.010, which is probably required.  The 0.001 .. 0.999 is intriguing.

Comment: Hm yeah you're right, the easiest solution would be to run it through another regex/simple string comparison that explicitly forbids the `0.000` case and then just do `\d{3}`.

Another ugly way to do it in one regex could be to take 3 cases: `[1-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9][1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{2}[1-9]`

Answer (score 0):

I am accepting @Crazysheep answer. Because that * caused the issue.

```
(^[0]?)\.(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,3}?$ seems to be working.
```

Tested at https://www.regex101.com/

Thank you all for quick response.

Comment: (a) This should probably be commentary, either to the accepted answer or to your question or edited into the question. (b) Have you checked for 0.010, 0.100, etc?  Should they be matched? Are they matched?

Comment: 0.010 , 0.100 should be matched and they matched. I got the expression working by removing * character and I did not try the solution provided by Crazysheep but I got my way through his answer. I would write it as a comment, thank you for pointing me.

Comment: @Sri I just want to point out that your regex matches things like `0.1` and `0.01`. It's also kind of convoluted - there's some weird interaction between how the regex engine works internally and how you're using lookaheads that makes it mostly work, but I would be careful with it.